# Any idea what data interchange format is used for the following below file and how can I parse it with some programming language

Tags: java, json, file, file-format

I need to parse the following kind of structure in java and manipulate the file for some automation process. Is it possible to parse it using some well defined parser. I am not aware of any data interchange format having such a file structure, it is not proper JSON AFAIK.

```
process NEW_PROCES {
    { PROPERTY1 localdomain }
    { PROPERTY2 {} }
    { PROPERTY3 {} }
    { PROPERTY4 {
        { PROPERTY5  {
            { ARGS1 {} }
            { ARGS2 {} }
            { ARGS3 {} }
        } }
        { RETRY -1 }
    } }
}
```

Comment: What is the filename?

Comment: its name is NetConfig